# Start typewriter effect when element is in the viewport

Tags: javascript, viewport, getboundingclientrect

I need to start a typewriter effect of a text element when it's visible in the viewport. I tried with getBoundClientRect but I think that I'm missing something. It starts always when the document is ready, so if you don't go fast to the element you can't see the effect. I tried also with a scroll event listener but the effect runs with the movement of the scroll.

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
let i = 0;
let txt = 'Natural . Imperfecto . Extraordinario';
let speed = 150;

function sectionActive () {
  let section = document.getElementById('typewriter');
  const boxPlace = section.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if (boxPlace.top = 200) {
    function typeWriter() {  
      if (i < txt.length) {
        section.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }
    typeWriter();
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(sectionActive);
```

thanks!!!

Comment: you aren't comparing but assigning in your `if(boxPlace.top = 200)` statement. You'll need to use a comparison operator (probably `<=` in this case?) but if you did mean equals, then `==` or `===`

Comment: Hi @pilchard . I've tried with `<=` and `==` and it doesn't work... thanks for your help!!